# Encoding / Decoding resulting only in alpha-numerical sequence

Tags: c#, algorithm, encoding

I am trying to develop a concept for a simple algorithm which will turn any data into a sequence composed of strictly letters (both upper case and lower case), as well as numbers. I'm sure there are plenty of ways to do this but I cannot seem to wrap my head around a decent idea. While there are plenty of ways of converting any given symbol into a letter/number, the tricky part will be turning the letter/number back into its original symbol (thus the reason I included decoding as part of the title).

I would like to know if anyone has done this before, and what do you suggest I try?

Comment: Hint: Base64 is awfully close to what you want.  (It includes a couple of non-alphanumeric chars as 'digits', but otherwise the idea matches up well.)  Encode after encrypting, and decode before you decrypt.  Unless by "encrypt" you mean "encode", in which case just do the encoding and decoding.   :)

Comment: See my comment below on the size issue please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you don't reinvent the wheel, and just use [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) instead. .NET has conversion built-in:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(arrayOfBytes)
```

P.S. That's an *encoding* by the way, which is what I think you mean - not *encryption*.

Comment: Ah, yes 'encoding'. Sorry about that. The problem with base64 is that it's greatly expanding the data I'm encoding. For example, if I base64 a 16kb file, the resulting string is nearly 40% larger. I want to keep the data size intact if at all possible.

Comment: Compress before encoding.  Other than that, you're SOL.  You can't arbitrarily turn 8 bits into 6 without losing information...the bits have to go somewhere.  In base64 and similar schemes, they just go into other bytes.

Comment: @Evan: Unfortunately, I'd say Base64 encoding is the most efficient in terms of space for arbitrary data. As you know, it's impossible to encode *any data* to a smaller character set and preserve size at the same time. If your particular data has a certain structure to it, then you may be able to implement a custom algorithm, or compress it before using Base64, but in general... you're out of luck :(

Comment: Alright guys, I'll suck it up for the time being then. Thanks.